# could not resolve dependency for scalabuff-runtime in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use the generated scala class in a sbt-managed class (using the scalabuff tool to generate the scala class from proto file https://github.com/SandroGrzicic/ScalaBuff). I now try to add the dependency to the sbt config:
addSbtPlugin("net.sandrogrzicic" %% "scalabuff-runtime" % "1.3.6")

But sbt reports the dependency could not be resoloved.

Anyone has similar issue before?

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the readme, scalabuff-runtime isn't the plugin, it's the runtime dependency. It looks like you actually [need](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalabuff)

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" %% "sbt-scalabuff" % "0.2")

libraryDependencies += "net.sandrogrzicic" %% "scalabuff-runtime" % "1.3.6"
```